# How can i show in a SELECT two columns of a table using PLUCK

Tags: php, laravel, forms, view, pluck

I'm trying to use the PLUCK method to display two columns of a table when selecting them

```
  $driverItems = Driver::pluck('driverName','id')->toArray();
```

[I need to display the driver name and the Licence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArAGK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluck()` will always create a single collection array (for multiple column pluck, it will be single object). Such as, this query output might look like:

```
{
  "driverName1": 1,
  "driverName2": 2,
}
```

You may try like following:

```
$driverItems = Driver::select('driverName','id')->get();
```

This will output like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "driverName": "driverName1"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "driverName": "driverName2"
    },
]
```

and for dropdown you can show it like:

```
<select >
@foreach($driveItems as $item)
  <option id="" value="{{$item.id}}"> {{ $item.driverName }} </option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pluck you can populate select

```
$driverItems = Driver::pluck('driverName','id')->prepend("---Select---","");
```

and in blade

```
<select name="driver_id">

   @foreach($driverItems as $key=>$value)

       <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option> 

   @endforeach

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `pluck()` and use **Form Facade** in the view file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$data = Driver::get();
$data=  Arr::pluck($data, 'driverName','id');
```

In view file,to create dropdown use below code:

```
{{ Form::select('element_name',$data,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'driver_list','placeholder'=>'-- Select --']) }}
```

It will create dropdown with place holder.